How to determine the computational complexity of my algorithm?
I set up an algorithm and I want to express its overall computational complexity by using big $O$ notation.
My input is a $ab \times ab$ dimension matrix $Y$, where $a$ is usually a constant, such as 3.
$b$ is a parameter, and $b$ could be very large. I need to solve an optimization problem $A+B+C$， where part $A$ is some constant times the squared Frobenius norm of the matrix $X-XY$. The dimension of $X$ is $n \times ab$, where $n$ is a constant, sample size.
The part $B$ is first, view matrix $Y$ is a $b \times b$ block matrix, where each block matrix has the dimension $a \times a$. Then compute the squared Frobenius norm of all these block matrices. This return another matrix $a \times a$, and we call it $Z$. Then do the element-wise product of Z. Then do the matrix exponential. The final step is to add all the diagonal elements.
The part $C$ is adding all the squared Frobenius norm of all these block matrices from the part $B$.
I use L-BFGS
optimization algorithm to solve the above problem. I can get the answer. But I want to know the overall computational complexity of my algorithm. So ideally, I want to say some functional form of $O(b)$.
